# How do I retrieve data in localStorage for me to call in the axios request header?

Tags: reactjs, axios, postman

This is my `axios`, how do I retrieve data in `localStorage` for me to call in the `axios` request header?

For example I want to get / post data to postman but we need a header to get the data:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://forexample/api',
  headers: {
    'timeout' : 30000,
    'APP_TOKEN': 'forexampe',
    'USER_TOKEN': JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data').data.DATA.TOKEN)
  }
})
```

and this is a data request that I will send to Postman using the header

```
async componentWillMount(){
    await API.post('url/api', this.state)
    .then((response)=> {
      let responJSON = response
    })
    console.log(this.state)
  }
```

how do I retrieve data in localstorage for me to call in the axios request header?

for example I want to get / post data to postman but we need a header to get the data

and this is a data request that I will send to Postman using the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

> The keys and the values are **always strings** (note that, as with objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).

So the reason that you're not getting the result you expect is you're trying to access nested data as if it were a real JS object.  This seems to be an issue with how you are storing the data, rather than how you are accessing it, as the `localStorage.getItem('myKey')` syntax you are using is ultimately correct.  What you want to do is store **only** the single value you want to access as its own explicit key in the localStorage object and remove all of the dot notation you have after your `getItem` call.